# get outputs of classifier layers from '.pt' pretrained AlexNet model

Tags: python, model

I have a '.pt' file that includes alexnet model which trained on my dataset. How I can get "out_features" of classifier  layers (layers 1 & 4) after running my model for different dataset.
I needs this data for inputs of SVM.

I have tried:
`Model(inputs, outputs=model.classifier[1].out_features)`
`model.classifier[1].out_features(inputs)`
`model.classifier[1].parameters(torch.tensor(inputs))`

but they didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first you have to load model

```
model = torch.load(model.pt)
```

after that you have to remove the last layer

```
features = list(model.classifier.children())[:-4]  # Remove last layer
model.classifier = nn.Sequential(*features)
```

then you can have the weights of last layer by applying model for inputs

```
out = model(inputs)
```